# How to convert a json object to a ReadOnlyMap<string, Foo> in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for a quick (and possibly, elegant) way to build a `ReadOnlyMap` from json data that presents itself as an object (keys are `strings`, and values fit nicely a type (let's call it `Foo`).

So, the following works but seems overly verbose and awkward to me:

```js
      const jsonData = { 'key1' : {...}, 'key2': {...} };
      const mutableMap = new Map<String, Foo>();
      for(const k in jsonData) {
        mutableMap[k] = jsonData[k];
      }
      const immutableMap: ReadOnlyMap<String, Foo> = mutableMap;
```

There is probably a near one-liner for this, but it's surprisingly hard to find. Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const immutableMap: ReadonlyMap<string, string> = new Map(
  Object.keys(jsonData).map(k => [k, jsonData[k]])
);
```

Comment: Nice! Thanks a lot! Playing a bit with your solution i found that this even works: 

`const immutableMap: ReadonlyMap<string, string> = new Map(Object.entries(jsonData));`

Comment: Oh yeah, sure. It's not supported in IE9 I believe. It came with ES8.